# Is there a university website that lists all books used/recommended per course in order?

Tags: university, books, online-resource, online-learning

That non-enrolled people can access, of course.

Comment: Depends on the university, the faculty, the lecturer .... just try a few university homepages and seek for courses that interest you.

Comment: Close voters:  this is not really a shopping question.  This is a "I want to use a university bookstore but I don't know what it's called" question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no one single website holding book information for every university and course everywhere.

Each course will have some information that they consider appropriate located somewhere but it won’t be in the same location for all.

Comment: It seems to me the question is about one university webpage that lists all books of their courses while your answer is about all books of all courses in ever universiry.

Comment: @user111388 and you are certain?

Comment: About what the question means? Or what?

Comment: Your comment seems like I offended you, which was not my intention. If you mean by "for every university and course everywhere" "for every course within one university", it is maybe a little bit misleading and you might want to change it. Anyway, no hard feelings and have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

In the US, universities are required to provide information on the web about required textbooks to students so that they can purchase the books from wherever they want without necessarily having to buy the textbooks from the college bookstore.

A search on Google using the name of the university and "required textbooks" will typically take you to a website that has this data.  You will probably need to cross-reference this information with the course catalog to know what courses are taken in what order within the academic program you're interested in.

In some cases, instructors will use materials that they've developed themselves and that students access through a course management system.  In that case, it's quite likely that the materials won't be visible to you.

Comment: Another place to look is the online ordering system of the university bookstore. They often allow you to search by course.

Comment: "universities are required to provide information on the web about required textbooks to students"  I don't believe you.  In particular, I do not believe it is required or that it is required to be "on the web" in particular.

Comment: See https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1015b for the regulations about publishing this information.  Typically this is implemented through the web site of the university bookstore, although it might be possible to provide the information on paper to students.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a university website that lists all books used/recommended per course in order?

Mostly yes.  At American universities you can visit the website of the campus bookstore.  This is usually a private company (not the university itself) which has gathered a list of required textbooks (not necessarily all books used) from faculty.  The bookstore will be happy to tell you what books you can buy for each course, even if you are are not a student.  A major limitation is that the websites usually only list recent courses.  If the course was not offered for a while, the information might have been deleted.